# Three.js Detection flat surface any object

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, 3d

I wonder how can I detect the flat surfaces of any object added to the scene. I want to draw PlanGeometry on any detected flat surface from a small distance of my object and I know how can I draw it but I have not any idea how to detect a flat surface. Someone can give me any leads or maybe someone knows some library which can help me?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "flat"? I assume you want to find the faces of an object that are part of the same plane? This can be done by computing the plane equation of a face and compare it to other faces. Three.js can be used to achieve this. Here is something to get you started:

1. Compute face (NOT vertex) normals and distance to origin using the property `normal` and method `.distanceToPoint(origin)` of [the face class](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/math/convexhull/Face)
2. Using normal and distance create a [Plane](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Plane)
3. Compare one face's plane with neighbors using a plane's `equals(plane)` method

Using this algorithm, you should be able to group all faces of an object into groups which share a common plane.

Comment: My point is that I want to find a flat surface whose area is greater than the value I have given. After that, I want to create a Plane which I can click and do some action

Comment: Okay, but this "flat surface" might be composed of multiple faces. The three steps above are a way to find faces that are part of the same plane.